# Unix: Simple Command Knowledge

Tags: unix, docker, cmd

What does each token specify (in regards to docker) in the following command?

> docker run --rm -it alpine chown nobody /

Comment: What do you mean by "Unix element"?

Comment: If you want to learn about the options of the command, then best start reading the "manual pages", so have a try with `man docker` and see where it leads you...

Comment: Each text element. i.e. what does "-it" mean? chown? nobody? Having "-" vs "--"?

Comment: Ok, as written: read the manual page.

Answer (score 1):

```
docker run --rm -it alpine chown nobody /
        |    |   ||      | |            |
        |    |   | ------   ------------
        |    |   |   |            |
        Start running a container
             |   |   |            |
             Delete the container when it's finished running
                 |   |            |
                 Interactive mode, attach to your terminal's stdin
                     |            |
                     Tag. Runs container tagged `alpine`
                                  |
                                  Run `chown nobody /` inside container
```

Note that the command `chown nobody /` won't do anything because the changes are lost as soon as the container exits.

Comment: You may want to show that all of the words/tokens after 'chown' are the arguments passed to 'chown', as it might be more clear that they are not used by docker directly.

Answer (score 0):

By running `docker run --help` you will see all the options and their meaning:

```
  -i, --interactive                    Keep STDIN open even if not attached
      --rm                             Automatically remove the container
                                       when it exits
```

As for the `chown nobody /`, this command runs on container startup.
This command will change the owner of root dir (which is aliased by `/`) to user `nobody`. The user [nobody](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186568/what-is-nobody-user-and-group) is a special user available in linux distributions.